# Fastest way to count number of distinct elements in array

Tags: c#, arrays, class, dictionary

I have a class of object like this:

```cs
public class Individual
{
    public double[] Number { get; set; } = new double[2]{ 0.0, 0.0 };
}
```

I stock these class in a list of dictionary and give values for Individual.Number:

```cs
selection = List<Dictionary<int, Individual>>
```

Now, I have to count the number of distinct values of `Individual.Number` (in the whole list). What I've done so far is:

```cs
selection.Values.SelectMany(list => list.Number).Distinct().Count();
```

I wonder if this is the fastest way to count? How can I improve the performance?

Thanks,

Comment: Your way is fine. I'd suggest avoiding [microoptimizing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding) unless you have an actual performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

Internally the [`Distinct()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,0ff831f61400afdf,references) method creates a new `Set<T>` without specifiying the size.

If you have a vague idea of the number of elements, this can prevent a number of allocations (and memory moves).

And since you only want the Count() You can include that directly (Credits @TimSchmelter).

```
    public static int OptimizedDistinctAndCount<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int numberOfElements) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        var set = new HashSet<TSource>(numberOfElements);
        foreach (TSource element in source) {
           set.Add(element);
        }
        return set.Count;
    }
```

You could then use:

```
selection.Values.SelectMany(list => list.Number).OptimizedDistinctAndCount(123);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this?

```
public class Individual
{
  public double[] Numbers { get; set; }
  public Individual()
  {
    Numbers = new double[0];
  }
  public Individual(double[] values)
  {
    Numbers = values/*.ToArray() if a copy must be done*/;
  }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    // Populate data
    var selection = new List<Dictionary<int, Individual>>();
    var dico1 = new Dictionary<int, Individual>();
    var dico2 = new Dictionary<int, Individual>();
    selection.Add(dico1);
    selection.Add(dico2);
    dico1.Add(1, new Individual(new double[] { 1.2, 1.3, 4.0, 10, 40 }));
    dico1.Add(2, new Individual(new double[] { 1.2, 1.5, 4.0, 20, 40 }));
    dico2.Add(3, new Individual(new double[] { 1.7, 1.6, 5.0, 30, 60 }));
    // Count distinct
    var found = new List<double>();
    foreach ( var dico in selection )
      foreach ( var item in dico )
        foreach ( var value in item.Value.Numbers )
          if ( !found.Contains(value) )
            found.Add(value);
    // Must show 12
    Console.WriteLine("Distinct values of the data pool = " + found.Count);
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

This approach eliminates some calling methods timings.

A further optimization would use for loops instead of foreach, and perhaps using a chained list instead of List (faster but requires more memory).